# Closure for operator with odd numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand this set of question and answer.

> Consider the set S of odd natural numbers, with respective operator $\Delta$.
>
> Let $\Delta$ be the multiplication. Is S closed under $\Delta$? Justify your answer

The answer that I have is:

> The S of odd integer numbers is closed under multiplication. To see that, notice that an odd
> integer number is of the form 2a + 1 for a some integer number. Then (2a + 1)(2b + 1) =
> 4ab + 2a + 2b + 1 = 2(2ab + a + b) + 1 which is again an odd integer number.

I understand everything until the "2(2ab + a + b) + 1" part.

It seems to be representing "2a + 1" which is an odd number. But how can I decide the "2ab + a + b" in the parenthesis is "a"?

Comment: $2(2ab + a + b) + 1$ is odd because is of the "form" $2k+1$ and it is iodd exactly because the division by $2$ gives a remainder of $1$. Of course, $k$ is not the same as $a$ ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So.. whatever is in the parenthesis, we can assume it to be $\mathbf k$? E.g. $\mathbf 2(7x - y * 2) + 1 = 2k + 1$?

Comment: It is just a question of notation (taken in general without $a=2ab+a+b$)

Comment: Notice that when they chose  to write the second  odd number  as $2b+1$  they used the letter $b,$ not the letter $a.$ So they did  not need  to use the letter $a$ in the other number either: For example: Let $x,y$ be odd. There are numbers $b,c$ where $x=2c+1$ and $y=2b+1.$ Then $xy=2a+1$ where $a=2cb+c+b$.....

Comment: (April 4th) You just deleted a question with binomial distribution. This is not a responsible attitude. Were you afraid that your teacher see it ?